# Adding algebraic inequality constraints in 'mpctools'

Tags: matlab, optimization, controls, mpc

I am using `MPCTools` package (from Rawlings group) in `MATLAB` to setup a Non Linear MPC problem and want to add inequality constraints in states and control (something like `2x1+5x2+9u1<=12` or `f(x1,x2,u1)<=12)` which needs to be satisfied at all times. These constraints need to be added in addition to bounding constraints on states, control and rate of change of control. How can I add these constraints?

I was able to add bounding constraints using `lb.u, lb.x,` however I do not know which field will have to be used for the above constraints